# Arcpy/CSV module extract many columns from GDB table and write to csv

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, csv, cursor

Below is part of a script i wrote a few months back when I was still learning python. Its part of a larger script, its works totally fine but it is really clunky and not 'pythonic'. It is pretty straightforward. I use an old gp searchcursor to loop through a GDB table. extract all the columns I want to variables. use a the .format() to order them properly, and write to the csv. I cannot just use the arcpy table to excel tool because I am only extracting certain columns in a particular order with different header names than the ones in the table.

```
def NullTest(item):
    formating function...
sorttable = arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(sortjoin, "sorttable")
z = 0
for x in gp.Searchcursor(sorttable):
    label2 = ''.join(str(NullTest(x.onflysort_OFlabel)))
    facidcsv = x.onflysort_FacilityID
    County = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_CountySEARCH)
    Municipality = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_MunSEARCH)
    FacilityName = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Facility_Name)
    Address = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Physical_Address)
    City = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_MunFacility)
    Contact = ''.join(str(NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Company_Contact)))
    ContactPhone = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Contact_Phone)
    x1 = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_XFINAL)
    y = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_YFINAL)
    DOT_Number = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_DOT_Number)
    Substance = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Substance)
    threesub = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_EPCRA_302_Substance)
    threesubabove = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_EPCRA_302_Above_Threshold)
    Inv = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Inventory)
    InvD = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Inventory_Description)
    reldur = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Release_Duration__min_)
    relrate = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Release_Rate_lb_min_)
    totalrel = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Total_Release)
    modelrun = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Model_Run)
    ZoneType = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Label)
    BufferDistance = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Buffer_Distance)
    Schools = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Schools)
    Childcares = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_ChildCare)
    Hospitals = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Hospitals)
    NursingHomes = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_NursingHomes)
    CI = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_CriticalInfrastructure)
    streamsw = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_StreamswithIntakes)
    streams = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_Streams)
    pop = NullTest(x.SiteChemByMunSort_ResidentialPopulation)
    header = "Id, FACID, County, Municipality, FacilityName, Address, City, Contact, ContactPhone, Xcoord, Ycoord, DOT_Number, Substance, 302 Substance?, 302 Above Threshhold?, Inventory, InventoryDescription, Release_Duration_min, Release_rate_lb_min,Total_Release,Model_Run, ZoneType, BufferDistance(Feet), Schools, Childcares, Hospitals, NursingHomes, Critical Infrastructure, StreamsWithIntakes(miles), Streams(miles), ResidentialPopulation, \n"
    row = "{},'{}',{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(label2,facidcsv,County,Municipality,FacilityName,Address,City,Contact,ContactPhone,x1,y,DOT_Number,Substance,threesub,threesubabove,Inv,InvD,reldur,relrate,totalrel,modelrun,ZoneType,BufferDistance,Schools,Childcares,Hospitals,NursingHomes,CI,streamsw,streams,pop)
    with open('C:\\Users\\rzagha\\Desktop\\RTK\\CRTKMunicipalityMaps\\csvs\\'+table['County']+' '+table['MunName']+'.csv', 'a') as wildcsv:
        if z==0:
            wildcsv.write(header)
            wildcsv.write(row)
        else:
            wildcsv.write(row)
    z+=1
```

I know i can use the arcpy.da searchcursor. How can make this code not so ridiculously long and clunky. and it does not seem I can use the csv module on a gdb table. are there any tricks I can use with the arcpy.da module?

**Modified script**
put my search cursor fields and new columns headers in their own tuples. and used the search cursor in list comprehension and used the writerows csv method to write them to the csv.

```
a = ('onflysort_OFlabel','onflysort_FacilityID','SiteChemByMunSort_CountySEARCH','SiteChemByMunSort_MunSEARCH','SiteChemByMunSort_Facility_Name')
b = ('SiteChemByMunSort_Physical_Address','SiteChemByMunSort_MunFacility','SiteChemByMunSort_Company_Contact','SiteChemByMunSort_Contact_Phone')
c = ('SiteChemByMunSort_XFINAL','SiteChemByMunSort_YFINAL','SiteChemByMunSort_DOT_Number','SiteChemByMunSort_Substance')
d = ('SiteChemByMunSort_EPCRA_302_Substance','SiteChemByMunSort_EPCRA_302_Above_Threshold','SiteChemByMunSort_Inventory')
e = ('SiteChemByMunSort_Inventory_Description','SiteChemByMunSort_Release_Duration__min_','SiteChemByMunSort_Release_Rate_lb_min_')
f = ('SiteChemByMunSort_Total_Release','SiteChemByMunSort_Model_Run','SiteChemByMunSort_Label','SiteChemByMunSort_Buffer_Distance')
g = ('SiteChemByMunSort_Schools','SiteChemByMunSort_ChildCare','SiteChemByMunSort_Hospitals','SiteChemByMunSort_NursingHomes')
h = ('SiteChemByMunSort_CriticalInfrastructure','SiteChemByMunSort_StreamswithIntakes','SiteChemByMunSort_Streams','SiteChemByMunSort_ResidentialPopulation')
csvtuple = a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h
header = ("Id, FACID, County, Municipality, FacilityName, Address, City, Contact, ContactPhone, Xcoord, Ycoord, DOT_Number, Substance, 302 Substance?,")
header2 = ("302 Above Threshhold?, Inventory, InventoryDescription, Release_Duration_min, Release_rate_lb_min,Total_Release,Model_Run, ZoneType, BufferDistance(Feet),")
header3 = ("Schools, Childcares, Hospitals, NursingHomes, Critical Infrastructure, StreamsWithIntakes(miles), Streams(miles), ResidentialPopulation,\n")
csvheader = ''.join(header+header2+header3)
with open('C:\\Users\\rzagha\\Desktop\\RTK\\CRTKMunicipalityMaps\\csvs\\'+table['County']+' '+table['MunName']+'.csv', 'a') as wildcsv:
        writer = csv.writer(wildcsv, lineterminator='\n')
        wildcsv.write(csvheader)
        csvarc = (row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sorttable, csvtuple))
        writer.writerows(csvarc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just brainstorming here, but maybe try something like this: make a list of your fields first, then pass that to the cursor. You can then join list comprehensions of the cursor's row objects to write into your csv.

*Edit*: If you need the CSV's header row to be different than the field names in the table, you'll need to either modify your fields list or make a separate headers list with the CSV headers you want (or use your existing header variable to write that row).

```
sorttable = arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(sortjoin, "sorttable")
fields =   [**list of all your fields**]  
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sorttable, [fields]) as cur:
      with open('C:\\Users\\rzagha\\Desktop\\RTK\\CRTKMunicipalityMaps\\csvs\\'+table['County']+' '+table['MunName']+'.csv', 'a') as wildcsv:
        wildcsv.write(", ".join([i for i in fields]))
        for row in cur:
          wildcsv.write(", ".join([str(i) for i in row])
```

Comment: yeah i was thinking someone along these lines. the hardest part would be matching up the new row names to the values in the specific order that I want. i may just have to keep it as manual..

Comment: In the cursor, the order of values in the row matches the order of fields specified by the field_names argument. So as long as your two lists are in the same order your values should map properly from the table to the csv. You could also use a list of dictionary objects to map {old field name : new field name} and derive each list from that.

Comment: ahhh I like the dictionary idea!

Comment: check out the way i did it. pretty similar to your idea. was just annoying to manually write create the tuples and headers